# Why can't I execute Kubectl after build on macOs

Tags: macos, kubernetes

I do the following...

```
myUser@... nunya % git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes
myUser@... nunya % cd kubernetes
myUser@... kubernetes % make
myUser@... cmd % cd cmd
myUser@... cmd % ./kubectl get namespaces
zsh: permission denied: ./kubectl
myUser@... cmd % sudo ./kubectl get namespaces
sudo: ./kubectl: command not found
```

`ls -al` says it is owned by that user...

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 myUser  staff   128 Jun 15 18:02 kubectl
```

So why am I getting the permission denied?

Comment: Did the answer below helped with your query?

Comment: Not sure it will take some time to check as for now I just chmod in the startup script

Answer (score 1):

As per the snippet you provided:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 myUser  staff   128 Jun 15 18:02 kubectl
```

This is a directory. Notice the first character of the permission is `d`. Perhaps you need to further `cd` to `kubectl` directory and try executing from there.  Here is an example where `foo` directory is created and supplied to `sudo` command.

```
ps@ps-vm:~$ mkdir foo

ps@ps-vm:~$ ls -lrt |grep foo
drwxrwxr-x 2 ps ps     4096 Jun 15 18:37 foo
ps@ps-vm:~$

ps@ps-vm:~$ sudo ./foo
sudo: ./foo: command not found
ps@ps-vm:~$
```